# Complete the sentences with the correct form of the following words

Tags: phrases

I need to complete the two sentences with the correct form of the following words: offer, make. The sentences:

1. Your exam grades _______ a big difference to your future career.
2. The supermarket _______ a good deal on frozen food at the moment.

How should I do this? I know phrases like "make a difference" and "make a deal" but I don't know phrases with "offer" and either of the two above words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your exam grades **make** a big difference to your future career.

You're looking for *make a difference*. The end of the sentence feels awkward, though. I've tried rewording it, but I'm having trouble making it sound natural without changing the wording much. Personally, I might say:

> Your exam grades have a big impact on your future career opportunities.

I think this is more accurate to your intent.

Getting back on topic...

> The supermarket **offers** a good deal on frozen food at the moment.
>
> The supermarket **makes** a good deal on frozen food at the moment.

Both of these are valid, but they come from opposite sides of the transaction. The customer *makes* a good deal on frozen food because the supermarket *offers* a good deal on frozen food. When you *make* a good deal, it is because you are buying the product for less or selling it for more. When you *offer* a good deal, it is usually because you are selling it for less.